Launching UI in dark mode
Basically what the title says, there's an icon top left on the UI app to switch the theme to dark. Is there any way to launch playwright test --ui in dark mode by default?
I've looked at the help options and a bunch of places on google with no luck

So the site doesn't have color preference auto-detect and the only way to go into dark mode is to hit the switch? If so, it  seems you'll need to toggle it in a beforeEach block just like any other button, and/or save storage state with userDataDir if the site happens to store that preference in localStorage.
